# How do I remove parts of this data?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, string-manipulation

The data:

```
{{9.99758, 0}, {"", ""}, {10.0178, -21.7137}, {"", ""}, {10.038, 
  28.5723}, {"", ""}, {10.0582, 0.52409}, {"", ""}, {10.0784, 
  21.7378}, {"", ""}, {10.0987, 0}, {"", ""},...}
```

I need to remove the empty points, i.e. the `{"", ""},` parts. I either need to find that pattern and remove it or simply remove every other point in this list.

In attempting to remove by pattern, I tried doing `data /. Part[data, 2] -> ""` but this returned:

```
{{9.99758, 0}, "", {10.0178, -21.7137}, "", {10.038, 
  28.5723}, "", {10.0582, 0.52409}, "", {10.0784, 
  21.7378}, "", {10.0987, 0}, "", {10.1189, 3.13778}, "",...}
```

How would I then finish it off by removing the `"",` part?

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out. It's simply `data[[1;; ;; 2]]`

Comment: `DeleteCases[{data, {"",  ""}]`

Answer (score 2):

### Preparation

```
lst = {{9.99758, 0}, {"", ""}, {10.0178, -21.7137}, {"", ""}, {10.038, 28.5723}, {"", ""}, {10.0582, 0.52409}, {"", ""}, {10.0784, 21.7378}, {"", ""}, {10.0987, 0}, {"", ""}};
```

### Solution 1

As @tomd pointed, you can:

```
DeleteCases[lst, {"", ""}]
(* ==> {{9.99758, 0}, {10.0178, -21.7137}, {10.038, 28.5723}, {10.0582, 0.52409}, {10.0784, 21.7378}, {10.0987, 0}} *)
```

### Solution 2

Or else, you can still use **Pattern Replace** by:

```
lst /. {"", ""} -> Sequence[] 
(* ==> {{9.99758, 0}, {10.0178, -21.7137}, {10.038, 28.5723}, {10.0582, 0.52409}, {10.0784, 21.7378}, {10.0987, 0}} *)
```

Comment: `{"", ""} -> Nothing` works in newer versions.

Comment: @J.M. It works! Thank you! I know one more thing!